# FIFO - Leave In Lieu vs Subbsitute leave validity check

Tags: sql, sql-server

It's about Leave in Lieu (replacement) leave, when a person work on
holiday entitle either 1 day or 0.5 days.

The validity of work on holiday allow to be claims within 3 months
only from the working date.

Let's say a Person A work on Holiday as below:

- 2018-01-27 - 1 day (Must clear the leave between 2018-01-27 to 2018-04-27 else burnt)
- 2018-01-28 - 1 day ( Must clear the leave between 2018-01-28 to 2018-04-28 else burnt )
- 2018-02-03 - 1 day ( Must clear the leave between 2018-02-03 to 2018-05-03 else burnt )

Person A Taking Substitute Leave on:

- 2018-02-21 - 1 day
- 2018-02-27 - 0.5 day
- 2018-03-13 - 1 day

Means:

- 2018-02-21 taken 1 day, will off set from 2018-01-27 => 0 Balance
- 2018-02-27 taken 0.5 day, will off set from 2018-01-28 => 0.5 Balance
- 2018-03-13 taken 1 day, will off set from 2018-01-28 0.5 day => 0 Balance;
- 2018-03-13 0.5 day remaining taken, will off set 2018-02-03 0.5 day => 0.5 Balance

**Output should be**

```
 Work Date  | Taken Date | Credit | Balance
 2018-01-27 | 2018-02-21 | 1      | 0
 2018-01-28 | 2018-02-27 | 0.5    | 0
 2018-01-28 | 2018-03-13 | 0.5    | 0
 2018-02-03 | 2018-03-13 | 0.5    | 0.5
```

How can I create an query beside using while...loop method? If I have
a huge data, while .. loop will caused the performance issue.

Please advise.

Regards,
Micheale

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I've reformatted half of your question, but you gave us a tough one to fix. Can you edit your question and cut and paste your code from something that was not forwarded through e-mail, with all the lines prefixed with `>`? Put three backticks before the beginning of a code block, and again after, that way it will look verbatim as you paste it, and we'll be able to read it.

Comment: Due to the rule of "Within 3 months of a work-on-hiliday the leave credit must be used or be discarded", I don't think you can avoid a looping structure. It can be done with recursion, but I'm not sure that's faster.

Comment: Hi George Menoutis, many thanks. Regards, Micheale